# Convert simple product to configurable

Tags: product, configurable-product, simple-product, conversion

I need to convert all the products of my ecommerce (about 1600) from simple to configurable. Is there a a way that doesn't involve adding from scratch all the products and, preferably, without editing the db tables?

Comment: I cannot see the logic behind that. What will be the simples you will put as associated products? Doing such without adding belonging simples will directly break your shop as no add to cart will exists anymore. You could export, change simple to configurable and import again. Of coarse you should remove products prior to importing. Also creating a back-up before anything of this.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to start from scratch.
The configurable products in Magento work like this:

- for each configurable option there is a simple product. Example. You want to configure a product by color and size. You need simple products with every combination of size and color you want to sell
- a configurable product is just a wrapper over the simple products described above.

So if you have the simple product already, you need to create the configurable product only and select as associated products the simple products that fit your needs.